# semantic ui: className doesn't work while style does

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Adding the style property works

```
<Card.Meta style={{ color: "#5D5C5C" }}>
  {calculateTime(post.createdAt)}
</Card.Meta>
```

While adding class does not:

```
<Card.Meta className="my-color">
  {calculateTime(post.createdAt)}
</Card.Meta>
```

What would you recommend to do in such case? I would prefer not to repeat inline styling

Answer (score 0):

About this issue, you might want to use **CSS module**, it's still CSS, but only affect in one component only.

**Note:** this would prefer to work with React app and webpack, I haven't tested with other environment =)))

File structure:

```
|
|_ MyComponent.module.css
|_ MyComponent.js
```

MyComponent.module.css:

```
.myColor {
  color: #5D5C5C;
}
```

MyComponent.js:

```js
import styles from './MyComponent.module.css';

...

<Card.Meta className={{styles.myColor}}>
  {calculateTime(post.createdAt)}
</Card.Meta>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! it wouldn't work, the way around it is to add a div inside of it

Answer (score 0):

Kind of stupid of me, you can just add a div inside and then apply the class to it